# Sample size for cross-cultural research

Tags: sample-size, survey-sampling

I am planning to conduct a study involving responses of people from two different countries.

Is there any consensus or rule of thumb about the minimum required sample size to test for cultural differences?

Perhaps it is worth noting that the potential respondents will be people with a semi-rare condition.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this cases the main issue is that you don't actually know the target  population (i.e. you don't have a list of people). I never worked to a similar study, but talking to people who did I heard of two possible solutions. The first one is oversampling the citizen population -- that is sampling a higher number of people than you would require to reach a given precision level -- in order to try and sample enough people in the rare population. The second one is respondent-driven sampling, you start from a subject you know and you ask him/her a list of other people in the same conditions.